# How do I print a JSON object received from Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, web-services

My Flask webapp returns jsonify(data) and seems to be working properly (logs correctly).

The HTML page has:

```
 $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:5000/").done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  });
```

and nothing is printed. I've tried different approaches and the closest I got was something like [object object].

The Python code is something like:

```
@app.route("/")  
def run():  
    rows = []
    # code to populate rows with values from a db
    data = {'rows' : rows}
    print json.dumps(data)
    return jsonify(data)
```

json.dumps() prints {"rows": [[[1.0, 2.0]]]}

Comment: That does not print anything either. With the Web Console, I can see that the response header has 'application/json' in it but there is no response body.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a bit late getting back to this.

I think that the problem is that you are trying to respond to the "done" event of the getJSON call.  The getJSON call is a wrapper for "ajax", but I bet that it overrides the "done" callback for the default function passed in.  Use getJSON this way:

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:5000", function(data) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2); 
    console.log(str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Better to print out the JSON string generated on the server side to make sure it is correct generated firstly.
- Then, For client side, you can put a break point on the client side javascript code and try to watch the value received from server side to make sure it's correct upon receiving.
- Then if you really want to print it out using console.log, you can use JSON.stringify method as described below.

Try

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:5000").done(function (data) {
    // indentation level = 2
    var str = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2); 
    console.log(str);
});
```

Please Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify for a detail description for method JSON.stringify.

Comment: I've tried all three options. The server side seems to be working as expected (also tested with curl). I had no luck in troubleshooting it with my browser's debugger. JSON.stringify does not work either (execution does not even seem to reach that point).